# How to efficiently manage YAML documents in Java with jacksoon-dataformat-yaml?

Tags: binding, jackson, docker-compose, yaml, schema

I am looking for suggestions on how to increase efficiency of synthesis of docker-compose.yml files from a Java application.  I would like to explore possibility of using Java-binding style mechanisms to do so (similar to what JAXB enables with XML).

It should be a very common thing people may want to do. Yet I am not able to find a description of a principled and well-defined approach to do it.

With XML I would feed XSD schema into a JAXB binding tool, which will generate for me a corresponding Java class hierarchy as well as [un-]marshalling code. I will then populate Java classes in memory and serialize them as XML files/streams.

Here are my questions:

- Is there such a concept as YAML schema?  Internet search leads me into multitude of directions, none of which seem to offer principled treatment of the subject.
- Has anybody seen a published schema for docker-compose formats? Do I have to write one myself for the textual spec defined here: (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)?
- Can jackson yaml tool import YAML schema and generate a Java class hierarchy?
- Examples of jackson yaml tool suggest that once I have a class hierarchy, I can write marshalling code myself and it is very straightforward, but it appears a bit more laborious than what JAXB marshaller use would be.

Any suggestions on the above points would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess nobody has a good answer for me, so I have solved the problem in a sub-optimal way, but still better than employing some sort of heuristic:

1. I created a simple XML schema containing a subset of data present in docker_compose YAML specification.  This is the only step in my process which is an approximation of the reality, and not a fully correct implementation.  The schema is incomplete and only includes stuff I care about.  I may extend it later as I develop needs for additional docker_compose options.
2. I am using JAXB to establish a binding from this approximate model to a Java class hierarchy.
3. I populated the classes from this hierarchy programmatically with data, and then used jackson yaml plugin to marshal a docker_compose.yml file with the content I needed.

This approach is very sub-optimal, but seems to work.  Still wish I could do it better, but will have to settle for this approximation at this point in time.  More suggestions are appreciated.